# How to realize .NET Process.Exited event by Win32 API only

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, process

On C#, it's very easy to detect whether the specific process ID was exited.

```
Process p = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
p.Exited += new EventHandler(OnExited);
```

What should I do for writing the same operation as this by Win32 API only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this the exact same way the .NET Process class does it.  Use [RegisterWaitForSingleObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685061%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the process handle.  Your callback will run when the handle gets signaled (ie the process completed) or the optional timeout expired.  Keep in mind that, like .NET, the callback runs on a theadpool thread so proper synchronization is required.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this code:
HANDLE wo = NULL;
 HANDLE h = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, pid);
 BOOL res = RegisterWaitForSingleObject(&wo,
  h, WaitCallback,
  0, INFINITE, WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE);
 CloseHandle(h);

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Hans' answer you can also synchronously wait on the process handle using `WaitForSingleObject`.